# How to include all data on Google data studio date range filter

Tags: looker-studio

I have this data on Google sheet:

| Date | agent | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 june | john | 12 |
| 1 june | billy | 24 |
| 2 june | carl | 36 |
| 2 june | billy | 48 |

The problem is when I add date range filter on that data, and I select 1 June, it only show

John : 12

Billy : 24

I would like it to also show

Carl : 0

How could I do that in Google data studio? Thanks for any help/suggestions

Answer (score 1):

There is a need to do a custom query connection in Data Studio. The date filter acts on the calulation not on the dataset. Therfore, each time a full table scan is done.

```
Select * , 
case when date<=PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE)  and date>=PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE) then amount else 0 end as amount_in_range
from(
Select current_date() as date,"A" as agent,1 as amount
UNION ALL Select '2021-11-02',"B",2
UNION ALL Select '2021-10-02',"C",3
)
```

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for the answer, can the custom query done on Google sheet as source data?